# ¿ Puedo borrar estos archivos sin que pase nada?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Tengo una aplicación en Android que me ocupa mucho y el 90% del total es por culpa de 3 archivos que no sé si se pueden borrar o qué pasaría si los borro.

El primero es fileSnapShots.bin, situado en .gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts , ocupa 22 MB, ¿ qué pasa si lo elimino ? ¿ Puedo prescindir de él? Es muy pesado...

El segundo y tercero es app-debug y app-debug-unaligned , situados en app\build\outputs\apk , ¿ los dos sirven? 9MB entre los dos

El tercero es mockable-android-23, situado en \build\generated , supongo que esto sirve para poder ejecutar la app en android studio, pero pesa casi 23MB.

> ¿ Algo de esto se puede borrar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondo a tus preguntas:

- Todo el contenido del folder `.gradle` dentro del directorio del proyecto puede ser eliminado pero será creado nuevamente cuando construyes el proyecto.

---

- En cuanto al folder  `\build`, contiene archivos que son generados al compilar, puedes borrar el contenido de este folder que contiene a su vez `\generated`  e `\intermediates`.

  **Si eliminas este folder veras reducido considerablemente el espacio en tu disco**, pero recuerda que al compilar se generan nuevamente.

---

- Los archivos contenidos dentro del folder `app\build\outputs\apk`, son .apk generados uno no alineado el cual puedes alinear mediante la herramienta **[Zipalign](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign.html)**, y el otro, **un .apk alineado el cual es candidato para subir a la playstore pero solo si este fue firmado con tu Keystore de producción, esto es muy importante.**

Answer (score 3):

Supongo que si lo borras no pasa nada, pero conlleva que tardará mucho más tiempo en generar y compilar el proyecto.

Yo normalmente uso dos espacios de desarrollo en diferente equipos y cuando quiero trasladar una app solo copio `build.gradle` y el `src`, todo lo demás lo genera.
Algunas veces me ha dado error el archivo `build.gradle`, pero lo soluciono con crear un proyecto en blanco y modifico los valores a partir del otro.

---

**Editado**

Sobre lo que pregunta del destino de los apk `app\build\outputs\apk` si quieres subir la app a google play services tienes que subir el `release-aligned` que se obtiene con firmar el apk.

---

### Generar Apk para subir a Google Play

Para publicar una App a `Google Play` la debes compilar/build en modo `release`
En la parte inferior izquierda de `Android-studio` hay una pestaña `Build variants` ábrela y selecciona `release`

El apk se debe signar y alinear, para ello debes generar un fichero `keystore`

Menu `Build->Generate Signed Apk` pulsas `Create New` y rellenas el formulario.

Cosas a tener en cuenta:

- **Alias:** pon tu nombre o corporación estilo: `apps.tunombreo.corporacion.com`
- **Password:** el password para firmar el apk.
- **Validity years:** yo pongo 100

Después puedes dar al `Build` una vez acabado se abrirar el explorer con los apk.
El que tienes que subir es el que contenga `release`

---

> **Cosas a tener en cuenta sobre el keystore**
>
> - Con un solo keystore, puedes firmar varias apps.
> - Importatisimo guardarlo permamente, en USB, en cloud, en la caja fuerte etc...
> - En futuras actualizaciones de tu APP, para volver a firmar, lo necesitas.

Documentación oficial [App signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Comment: Pero a qué te refieres con borrar no pasa nada? Borrar esas 3 cosas? Lo de mockable en verdad no es para ver en pantalla los layouts desde la aplicacación? Por cierto, el app debug para que sirve?

Comment: que todo lo que está dentro de la carpeta .gradle cuando ejecutes de nuevo el android studio con el proyecto, gradle creará lo que necesita o bien cuando haces build