# Archivos generados por ejecuciones en Android-studio

Tags: android-studio

Me gustaría saber qué archivos de un proyecto de android studio se generan en la ejecución automáticamente y por ello no son necesarios para importar el proyecto en otro ordenador.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas llevar tu proyecto a otra pc principalmente evita copiar principalmente el contenido del folder `/build`, todo lo generado dentro de este folder se crea al construir el proyecto.

Existen otros archivos, por ejemplo R.java pero pueden considerarse no tan importantes ya que su tamaño no es considerable.

[¿ Puedo borrar estos archivos sin que pase nada?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23367/puedo-borrar-estos-archivos-sin-que-pase-nada/23475#23475)

Como ejemplo tengo un proyecto que pesa 20MB pero en ocasiones llego a tener 400MB todo el proyecto con el contenido que se genera dentro del directorio `/build`, el cual es innecesario ya que se vuelve a generar.

Answer (score 0):

Fijate mi respuesta en esta otra pregunta:

[Limpiar código android studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83311/limpiar-c%C3%B3digo-android-studio/83344#83344)

Ahí puse la lista de archivos default que Git ignora al momento agregar version control a tu proyecto con esta herramienta.

Es una buena base para tu pregunta.

En mis proyectoas normalmente agrego más archivos a la lista según el proyecto y lo que necesito. Por ejemplo si el build me genera los apk en la carpeta app, también agrego los *.apk.